# How to use environment variables in applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, leopard, environment-variables

I'd like to use my environment variables, which were defined in my environment.plist file, in my applescript.

How do I do that, for instance:

```
log "Glassfish Home: " & AS_HOME
```

Where AS_HOME is my environment variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
log "Glassfish Home: " & (system attribute "AS_HOME")
```