# Applescript to set environment variable before opening terminal

Tags: terminal, applescript, bash, automator

I have the following Applescript in a workflow assigned to a service hotkey that opens a terminal in a given Finder window:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set myWin to window 1
    set thePath to (quoted form of POSIX path of (target of myWin as alias))
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        tell window 1
            do script "cd " & thePath
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

I would like to set an environment variable before the terminal is invoked so that when `.bash_profile` is sourced, an if statement checking for the existence of said environment variable passes.

I've seen methods to access environment variables, such as [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92919/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-applescript), but nothing that *sets* environment variables for the following shell session.

I have tried to change the terminal line to `do script "my_env_var=some_value; cd " & thePath`, but I need it set before the session starts. I also tried to set the variable in a `do script` before the one that opens the shell I want to use:

```
do script "my_env_var=some_value"
do script "cd " & thePath
```

But this just opens two shells and does the same as before.

Is there a way to accomplish setting this environment variable, or perhaps determining if the terminal was invoked by this service rather than another method?

Comment: Is there some reason why you just don't edit the `.bash_profile` file directly and be done with it?

Comment: @user3439894 I have byobu set to open on default when a new terminal is opened, this is based on a variable that is set when `.bash_profile` is sourced. I want to skip that line to avoid opening the shell with byobu when I use the service to open the terminal in the given finder location. I wouldn't mind byobu being used, but all instances of byobu use the same buffer. Also, the `cd` gets gobbled up before byobu is activated.